# C++ / CLI XML XmlObjectSerializer abstract class

Tags: .net, c++-cli, xmlserializer

I am using .net 3.5. 
**In a C# project** i can  access XmlObjectSerializer as

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer
```

but **in C++ / CLI project** i can **not** able to use that class as

```
 System::Runtime::Serialization::XmlObjectSerializer
```

What is the problem? Why i can not able to reach that class under C++/CLI?

Best Wİshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sounds simply like a missing assembly reference to assembly:  System.Runtime.Serialization (in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)